# Can I remove the text beneath apps on the iOS 7 home screen (SpringBoard)?

Tags: ios, springboard

The text beneath the apps looks really out of place with the new iOS 7. Is there any way to turn it off without jailbreaking?

Answer (score 1):

No this is not possible. Not in the standard iOS package anyway.

I have no experience with jailbroken iOS, but I would assume so, although there is no JB for iOS 7 just yet.